# Fetch Col values from one Table for which cols are represented as Row values in Different Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following tables in my database:

**Table T1:**

```
Item | Week

101  | Week1

101  | Week2

102  | Week1

102  | Week3
```

**Table 2:**

```
Item | Week1 | Week2 | Week3

101  | 10    |10     | 20

102  | 20    | 20    | 30
```

I want the Output as:

```
Item | Total_Value

101  | 20

102  | 50
```

Here are the requirements:

- Select the Row values from Table1 and fetch and aggregate the column values from the other table for the selected row values (Row value of Table1 = Col name of Table2).
- Need a Solution which is more Performance efficient as the Weeks can range from 1..104.
- Coding to be performed in Oracle 11g;preferably a solution that could work in Lower versions as well. But Performance is a priority :)
- Pseudo code would be of a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should normalize your table2

Comment: The problem with your data model is that  you say "weeks can range from 1..104". So, that means effectively your table t2 could have 1 to 104 columns, which sounds like a poor design.  Although you may be able to unpivot t2 and then join with t1, still it will have to be dynamic `unpivot`. So, if you are just writing it to clear a test, you may attempt it, otherwise it is better to revamp your data model.

Comment: Table2 has actually 104 Week columns along with other not so imp columns.if there is no data in a particular week for a particular item it will b represented as NULL.
So whichever weeks are found in Table1 I have to pick up their values from Table2 and aggregate.
Moreover there are thousands of items as well :(
I can't change the data model.

Comment: This is a very, very bad data model and selecting the data ad hoc will never be fast. A pity that you are not allowed to change the data model. So the DBAs who forbid this should at least provide a materialized view on the unpivoted table2 for quicker access in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot table2 with something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2
UNPIVOT (item FOR week IN (week1 AS 'Week1', week2 as 'Week2', .....));
```

and you can join table1 and table2 in the conventional fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. :)
I can UNPIVOT table2 and store it in a GTT , and query the GTT every time I need, I think that will make it performance effiicient. But will UNPIVOT be performance efficient if there are 104 weeks and thousands or millions of Items?

Comment: No less efficient than any other means of mapping those 104 columns to 0-104 rows in the other table.  Its really a design issue - but if you are bound by the current design, then you really don't have many options besides unpivoting in *some* form

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response .It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments,a better approach would be to change the Table design. You said,

> Table2 has actually 104 Week columns

So, are those columns indeed `Week1,week2,week3 ...week104`?

A query with `UNPIVOT` for the 3 columns you have shown would be something like this.

```
SELECT Item
    ,SUM(val) as Total_Value
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T2
    UNPIVOT(val FOR Week IN (
                 Week1 as 'Week1'
                ,Week2 as 'Week2'
                ,Week3 as 'Week3'
                ))
    ) t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t1
        WHERE t1.Item = t.Item
             AND t1.Week = t.week
        )
GROUP BY Item
Order By Item;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a2967/42)

Notice that we must  write `Week? as  'Week?'`  for every available column, which itself is of course a bit tedious and leads to unnecessarily long query. So, think carefully and implement it if you actually want it that way or else come up with an alternate design.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

*Union all* might also useful

```
select t2.Item, sum(t2.value) Total_value from (
    select item, week1 as value, 'Week1' weeks from t2 union all
    select item, week2 as value, 'Week2' weeks from t2 union all
    select item, week3 as value, 'Week3' weeks from t2 ) t2
where exists (
    select 1 from t1 
    where item = t2.item and Week = t2.weeks)
group by t2.Item
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yogesh.But I think Unpivot works better when I have 104 records.let me know if u have different views. :)